# Locating or Establishing MySQL UN and PW after uploading .sql file via phpMyAdmin (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I've uploaded a `.sql` file via `phpMyAdmin` with success. I am currently using a different table in my Wordpress installation, but would like to switch it to the table/.sql file I just uploaded.

I know in the wp-config.php file I need to update the following to reflect the new file I uploaded:

`define('DB_NAME' 'name goes here')` - I've got this

`define('DB_USER' 'usernamegoeshere')` - need to find/establish

`define('DB_PASSWORD' 'passwordgoeshere')` - need to find/establish

My question is: where do I find or establish a username and password associated with the new db file I uploaded? Do I use the exisiting username and password from the current db in use?

Just a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

You uploaded sql file and imported it to database.

For connect to this database you should use same username and password what you use for phpMyAdmin login.